# Fetch top samples & random samples from a Presto table whose data type is not known

Tags: sql, mysql, hive, presto

I am building a UI tool that shows some data to the user. The user can select any Presto table & column from the tool. The tool queries that table & column_name & fetches

a) 10 random samples from that column

b) Shows the frequency of data within that column

I implemented the two queries like this -

10 random samples

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
LIMIT 10;
```

Frequency of data

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY frequency DESC;
```

Now, the problem is that the columns in Presto can contain complex data types such as Maps & the above queries throw an error when the column in question contains complex data types. I do not know which columns contain complex data types before hand & I cannot restrict the user from querying against those table.

I tried to CAST the columns as VARCHAR but it cannot CAST a map to a string. Is there a way to implement the queries in a way that it works for all types of data within the column?